# Backpropagation overall error chart with very small slope... Is this normal?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I'm training a neural network with backpropagation algorithm and this is the chart of Overall Errors:

[image]

( I'm calculating Overall error by this formula : http://www.colinfahey.com/neural_network_with_back_propagation_learning/neural_network_with_back_propagation_learning_en.html   Part 6.3 : Overall training error)

I have used Power Trendline and after calculations, I saw that if epoches = 13000 => overall error = 0.2

Isn't this too high?

Is this chart normal? Seems that the training process will take too long... Right? What should I do? Isn't there any faster way?

**EDIT : My neural network has a hidden layer with 200 neurons. and my input and output layers have 10-12 neurons. My problem is clustering characters. (it clusters Persian characters into some clusters *with supervised training*)**

Comment: What are the inputs and target output(s)? Are you using a single hidden layer? How many neurons are in the hidden layer(s)?

Comment: @BenHocking Question updated.

Comment: The curve looks similar to ANNs that I have trained before. It may be that the problem is to complex for the ANN to learn, or that your training data isn't optimal. Are you using any libraries or is it all from scratch?

Comment: I have my neural network class (I don't use any libraries) . Also my learning rate is 0.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using a ANN with 200 input nodes with 10-12 hidden nodes in the hidden layer, what activation function are you using if any for your hidden layer and output layer?

Is this a standard back propagation training algorithm and what training function are you using? 
Each type of training function will affect the speed of training and in some cases its ability to generalise, you don't want to train against your data such that your neural network is only good for your training data.

So ideally you want decent training data that could be a sub sample of your real data say 15%.
You could training your data using conjugate gradient based algorithm:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/nnet/ug/bss331l-1.html#bss331l-2
this will train your network quickly.

10-12 nodes may not be ideal for your data, you can try changing the number in blocks of 5 or add another layer, in general more layers will improve the ability of your network to classify your problem but will increase the computational complexity and hence slow down the training.

Presumably these 10-12 nodes are 'features' you are trying to classify?

If so, you may wish to normalise them, so rescale each to between 0 and 1 or -1 to 1 depending on your activation function (e.g. tan sigmoidal will produce values in range -1 to +1):
http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/706

You may also train a neural network to identify the ideal number of nodes you should have in your hidden layer.

Comment: No, my ANN has 10-12 input nodes and 10-12 output nodes and 200 hidden nodes!

Comment: 200 hidden nodes sounds very high compared to the number of input nodes you have, normally your hidden layer will be of the same magnitude so in your case I would expect between 5-30 hidden nodes, otherwise your hidden nodes are saturating your values. If you think about it you are feeding characteristics to the network and asking it figure out how to solve the multi dimensional function that will accurately solve the function. So do you expect there to be 200 dimensions given you have only 10-12 inputs? What are your inputs?